# ERROR: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, django

I try to import Response from requests in Django :

```
from requests import Response
```

Error :

```
  from requests import Response
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Comment: Did you try installing the module?

Comment: Do `pip install requests`.

Comment: I will try to install it. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install requests by running `pip install requests` from your cli. This lib is not part of your default python setup.

Comment: My pleasure :). Good luck!